# How to disable authenticated access in Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

For dev and testing environments, I would like to disable authenticated `@RestController` access entirely throughout the application.

Is there any advantage or disadvantage using configured `.anonymous()` access over `.permitAll()`? Both works...

```
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    return http.anonymous().build();
    
    //or
    return http.authorizeExchange()
            .anyExchange().permitAll()
            .build();
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding the difference of permitAll() and anonymous() in Spring Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51395906/understanding-the-difference-of-permitall-and-anonymous-in-spring-security)

Comment: You can try creating a dev profile and specify this in your application-dev.properties `security.basic.enabled=false`

Comment: [Anonymous Authentication](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/anonymous.html)

Comment: @Toerktumlare that's interesting, thanks. Anyways the linked question does not clearly answer what the exact difference is, merely which approach to chose in which situations. Apart from that `.anonymous()` will always populate the spring security context, which might be better as then every service can rely on the authentication without having to care for `null` authentication.

Comment: @user1738539 `security.basic.enabled` is deprecated!

Answer (score 0):

if you want everyone(authenticated or unauthenticated) to access your url go with permitall() ,but if want your url to access only by unauthenticated users use anonymous()